# Send and Receive upto 200KB over TCP/IP socket

Tags: c, socket, tcp

Code reviewers, I have changed code whatever be suggested by code reviewer and I want you to give me some feedback on the basis of my new code.

I have written TCP server client code to send data of any size (1 byte - 200KB) in a loop.

The client (A) sends data to the server (B). B then sends the same data back to A. A matches the sent data to the data received. If the data does not match, control flow will break from the while-loop. If the data matches, the loop will continue to 200K bytes and then break successfully.

This question is a follow-up question on [Send and Receive more than 64KiB over TCP/IP socket](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195955/send-and-receive-more-than-64kib-over-tcp-ip-socket)

Server code (server.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "init.h"

#define MAX_CLIENT 20000
#define SIZE 220000

int server_listen(int argc, char **argv);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret, accept_desc, n, ssd;
    unsigned int bytes = 1;
    unsigned char *buf;
    fd_set rfd;

    ssd = server_listen(argc, argv); // --- return fd from listen()
    n = ssd;

    FD_ZERO(&rfd); // --- Clears a set
    FD_SET(ssd, &rfd); // --- Add a given file descriptor from a set

    while (true) {
        FD_ZERO(&rfd);
        FD_SET(n, &rfd);
        ret = select(n + 1, &rfd, NULL, NULL, NULL); // --- Waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready"

        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("Error in select\n");
            close(n);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(ssd, &rfd)) { // --- Tests to see if a file descriptor is part of the set
            accept_desc = server_accept(ssd); // ---Accept connection from client
            fprintf(stderr, "client %d is connected\n", accept_desc);
            if (n < accept_desc)
                n = accept_desc;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(accept_desc, &rfd)) {
            bytes++;
            buf = receive(accept_desc, bytes); // --- Receive buffer from client
            if(buf == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory not allocated\n");
                close(accept_desc);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            send_str(accept_desc, buf, bytes); // --- Send received buffer to client
            fprintf(stderr, "sent %d\n", bytes);
            free(buf); // --- Free the memory
        }
    }
}


int server_listen(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ssd, flag = 1, ret, portno;
    unsigned int addrlen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    portno = get_option(argc, argv); // --- Get portno from user using getopt

    ssd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // --- socket creates an endpoint for communication

    if (ssd < 0) {
        perror("Error in socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ret = setsockopt(ssd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY,
            (char *) &flag, sizeof(int)); // --- TCP_NODELAY used to disable nagle's algorithm
    if (ret != 0) {
        perror("Erro in tcp_nodelay");
        close(ssd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ret = setsockopt(ssd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
            (char *) &flag, sizeof(int)); // --- SO_REUSEADDR to reuse same port

    if (ret != 0) {
        perror("Error in reuseAddr");
        close(ssd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons((uint16_t)portno);
    bzero(&serv_addr.sin_zero, sizeof(serv_addr.sin_zero));
    addrlen = sizeof(serv_addr);

    ret = bind(ssd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, addrlen); // --- Bind assigns the address specified by addr to socket

    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("Error in binding");
        close(ssd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Bind completed\n");
    //Listen
    ret = listen(ssd, MAX_CLIENT); // --- ready to accept incoming connection requests using accept()

    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("Error in listen");
        close(ssd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "listen\n");

    return ssd;
}
```

Client code (client.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include "init.h"

#define KB 1024
#define NO_EXIT_OR_ERROR 1
#define STATE_SEND 0
#define STATE_RECEIVE 1

unsigned int bytes;

struct hostent *server;

int client_connect(int argc, char **argv);

unsigned char *fill_n_send(int fd);

void receive_n_compare(int fd, unsigned char *buf_send);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, state = STATE_SEND, ret;
    struct timeval tv;
    unsigned char *buf_send;
    fd_set rfd;

    fd = client_connect(argc, argv); // --- Return fd from connect()
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 100;

    FD_ZERO(&rfd); // --- Clears a set
    FD_SET(fd, &rfd);

    while(NO_EXIT_OR_ERROR) {
        FD_ZERO(&rfd);
        FD_SET(fd, &rfd); // --- Add a given file descriptor from a set
        ret = select(fd + 1, &rfd, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        if(ret < 0) { // --- Waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready"
            perror("Select error");
            close(fd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(state == STATE_SEND) {
            buf_send = fill_n_send(fd);
            state = STATE_RECEIVE;

        }

        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &rfd)) { // --- Tests to see if a file descriptor is part of the set
            receive_n_compare(fd, buf_send);
            state = STATE_SEND;
        }
    }
}


unsigned char *fill_n_send(int fd)
{
    unsigned int start = 0;
    unsigned char *buf_send;

    buf_send = malloc(bytes + 2);
    if(buf_send == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory not allocated\n");
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(start <= bytes){ // --- fill send buf like A, AA, AAA, AAAA ..... upto 200KB size and send one by one like first A then AA then AAA ...
        buf_send[start] = 'A';
        start++;
    }
    buf_send[++bytes] = 0;

    if(bytes >= 200*KB) {
        free(buf_send);
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    send_str(fd, buf_send, bytes + 1);

    return buf_send;
}


void receive_n_compare(int fd, unsigned char *buf_send)
{
    unsigned char *buf_recv;

    buf_recv = receive(fd, bytes + 1);

    if(buf_recv == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory not allocated\n");
        free(buf_send);
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(strcmp((const char*)buf_send, (const char*)buf_recv) == 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Match\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unmatch %ld %ld\n", strlen((const char*)buf_send), strlen((const char*)buf_recv));
        close(fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    free(buf_send);
    free(buf_recv);
}


int client_connect(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd1, ret, flag = 1, portno;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    portno = get_option(argc, argv); // --- Get portno from user using getopt

    if(server == NULL) { // --- Check whether receive ip address of server
        fprintf(stderr, "Assign IP\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fd1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // --- socket creates an endpoint for communication
    if (fd1 == -1) {
        perror("ERROR on creating Socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", fd1);
    fprintf(stderr, "socket created successfully.\n");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *) server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         (long unsigned int)server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons((uint16_t)portno);

    ret = setsockopt(fd1, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY,
            (char *) &flag, sizeof(int)); // --- TCP_NODELAY used to disable nagle's algorithm

    if (ret != 0) {
        perror("Error in setsockopt");
        close(fd1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (connect(fd1, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1) { // --- Connect the socket to the server
        perror("ERROR in Connecting");
        close(fd1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Client connected Successfully\n");

    return fd1;
}
```

Initial definition (init.c):

```
#include "init.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE 220000

struct hostent *server;

unsigned char *receive(int csd, unsigned int size)
{
    long int ret;
    unsigned char *buf = malloc(size), *buf1 = NULL;

    if(buf != NULL) {
        memset(buf, 0,size);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory not allocated\n");
        close(csd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(true) {
        ret = recv(csd, buf, size, 0);

        if(buf[ret-1] > 0) {
            buf1 = malloc(size);

            if(buf1 != NULL) {
                memset(buf1, 0,size);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory not allocated\n");
                free(buf);
                close(csd);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            strcpy((char*)buf1, (const char*)buf);
            memset(buf, 0, size);
            continue;
        }

        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("Error in receive\n");
            close(csd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (ret == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "client disconnected\n");
            close(csd);
        } else {

            if(buf1 != NULL) {
                strcat((char*)buf1, (const char*)buf);
                free(buf);
                return buf1;
            }
            return buf;
        }
    }

}


void send_str(int csd, unsigned char *buf, unsigned int size)
{
    long int ret;

    ret = send(csd, buf, size, 0);

    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("Error in send\n");
        close(csd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if(ret == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Nothing to send\n");
        close(csd);
    }
}


int server_accept(int ssd)
{
    int accept_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    socklen_t cli_addr_len;

    accept_desc = accept(ssd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,
                  (socklen_t *)&cli_addr_len);

    if (accept_desc < 0) {
        perror("Error in accept\n");
        close(ssd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return accept_desc;
}


int get_option(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt, portno = 0;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "p:i:")) != -1) {

        switch (opt) {

        case 'p':
            portno = atoi(optarg);
            memset(&optarg, 0, strlen(optarg));
            break;

        case 'i':
            server = gethostbyname(optarg);
            memset(&optarg, 0, strlen(optarg));
            break;

        default: /* '?' */
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);;
        }
    }

    if (portno == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Assign port number\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("portno = %d optind = %d\n", portno, optind);

    return portno;
}
```

Initial declaration (init.h):

```
#ifndef INIT_H
#define INIT_H

int get_option(int argc, char *argv[]);

unsigned char *receive(int csd, unsigned int size);

void send_str(int csd, unsigned char *buf, unsigned int size);

int server_accept(int ssd);

#endif // INIT_H
```

Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all server1 client1

all: server1 client1

server1: server.c init.c
        gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 server.c init.c -o s

client1: client.c init.c
        gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 client.c init.c -o c

server:
        ./s -p 13000

client:
        ./c -p 13000 -i 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send and Receive more than 64KiB over TCP/IP socket](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195955/send-and-receive-more-than-64kib-over-tcp-ip-socket)

Comment: Hi @Coal_ please tell me is it correct now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` or `realloc()`, always check the returned value is not null to assure the operation was successful.

When communicating over a TCP/IP, connection, the data (especially after about 1650 bytes in a single packet) will break the data into multiple packets. Therefore your code needs to expect that kind of event. I suggest using a 'sliding window', in a loop, until all the data is sent/received.

The Makefile has rules named `client` and `server` but that Makefile, as written, will not execute those two executables (especially at the same time).

In the Makefile, the rules `server1` and `client1` do not list the header file `init.h` as a dependency, so if/when the header file is modified, the executables will NOT be rebuilt.

Regarding `ret = listen(ssd, MAX_CLIENT);`, for this to have ANY chance of handling 20000 clients each, the client should be passed to a 'thread pool' entry. As it is, only 1 client will be accepted at a time. All other clients will receive an error indication.

Comment: Hi @user3629249 can you please show me where I can't check (!=NULL).

Comment: I can't see any unchecked allocations - please be more specific which one you think is missing the necessary check.

Answer (score 1):

The Makefile could be improved:

- Without a `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` target, Make won't remove outputs of commands that fail.  Every Makefile should have this target.
- `server1` and `client1` are marked as `.PHONY`, but they produce actual files (`s` and `c` respectively); these will be written even when up to date.
- `server` and `client` are not marked as `.PHONY`, but their rules should be run even if such files exist.
- `server` and `client` don't depend on their respective programs, so may invoke out-of-date code
- The above points could be avoided with a clearer naming convention: I like to use nouns (or obvious filenames) for real targets and verbs for phony targets.  In this case, it would be `server` and `client` for the programs and `run-server` and `run-client` to execute them.
- We can make better use of built-in rules if we set `CFLAGS` appropriately.
- Instead of compiling `init.c` twice, we could make both client and server depend on `init.o`.  Then it will be compiled just once, and linked into both programs.

On the positive side, I'm pleased to see a good level of warning options enabled.

---

Here's my suggested replacement (I'm assuming GNU Make):

```make
CC = gcc

CFLAGS = -std=gnu11
# Debugging
#CFLAGS += -g
# Optimisation
#CFLAGS += -O2
# Warnings
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic

all: server client

server: server.o init.o
client: client.o init.o

server.o: init.h
client.o: init.h
init.o: init.h


run-%: %
    ./$< $(RUN_ARGS)

run-server: RUN_ARGS = -p 13000
run-client: RUN_ARGS = -p 13000 -i 127.0.0.1


clean::
    $(RM) client server *.o *~

.PHONY: all run-% clean
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
```

Comment: Can you please tell me one thing, How can I use recv() with MSG_DONTWAIT flag so I can use it without error. Current I am working on this and I am facing issue with recv() although my send() works fine with MSG_DONTWAIT.

Comment: I haven't looked at the C code yet.

Comment: ok no problem, If you know anything please let me know. thanks